# Render User Count With React / Websockets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I have a server file which sends data with Websockets here. As you see, I have a counter which I defined as `clientCount` and I want to increase/decrease it based on how many users are connected to my host. So far I'm able to show the connections in my console but not in my React App.

```
const wss = new SocketServer({ server });

let clientCount = 0;

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  console.log('Client connected');
  clientCount++;

  console.log(clientCount);

  ws.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log('Message from client', message);

    let parsedMessage = JSON.parse(message);

    parsedMessage.id = uuid();
    console.log(message); 

    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) { 
      if (client.readyState === ws.OPEN) {
        client.send(JSON.stringify(parsedMessage));
      }
    });
  });

  ws.on('close', () => {
    console.log('Client disconnected');
    clientCount--;
  });

});
```

Here in my React App, under my `componentDidMount()` I'm configuring my state to display in my console with the username/conent but that's irrelevant information.

In my `render` call inside a paragraph tag, I want to display the amount of users online in that field and updating every time they connect to the host, and disconnect. How do I display that information?

```
componentDidMount() {

    this.socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3001")

    this.socket.onmessage = (event) => {

      let message = JSON.parse(event.data)

      this.setState({
        messages: this.state.messages.concat([{
          username: message.username,
          content: message.content,
          id: message.id
        }])
      })

      console.log(JSON.parse(event.data));
    }
}

  render() {
    const {currentUser, messages} = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar">
          <a href="/" className="navbar-brand">Chatty</a>
          <p>RENDER USER COUNT HERE</p>
        </nav>

        <MessageList messages={messages} />      
        <ChatBar userProp={currentUser.name} messages={messages} submitMessage={this.newMessage}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What `SocketServer` class is that using?

Comment: @Aaron thinking of using the `connection` class

Answer (score 0):

You can make `clientCount` Observable. And then subscribe its changes in your react component. Every time `clientCount` changes, use setState to tigger a view update.

like this

```
class YourComp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { count: 0 }    
  }

  onCountChange = (newCount) => {
    this.setState({ count: newCount})
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    clientCountObservable.subscribe(this.onCountChange)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clientCountObservable.unsubscribe(this.onCountChange)
  }
}
```

a simple Observable would be like

```
class Observable {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value
    this.subscribers = []
  }

  subscribe(subscriber) {
    this.subscribers.push(subscriber)
  }

  unsubscribe(subscriber) {
    const index = this.subscribers.indexOf(subscriber)
    if (index > -1) {
      this.subscribers.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }

  setValue(value) {
    this.value = value

    this.subscribers.forEach(sb => sb(value))
  }

  getValue() {
    return this.value
  }
}
```

You can create your own observable class, or use some other npm package.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Where exactly is `clientCountObservable` coming from? Do I have to make that myself?

Comment: You can create your own Observable class. There are many ways to create it.